# Google Maps Traffic Flow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am developing a iOS application and I intend to use Google Maps API and I have couple of questions:

Can we display Google Maps Traffic Flow-Red, Yellow and Green lines- Information on our application?

Is Traffic Flow is live one?

Can we get Historical Traffic Flow? Like I want to show what is the usual traffic flow at a given period of time, i-e at 9 AM it's usually red traffic flow at a certain location based on history?

Thanks,

Attiqe

Comment: Please check this questions and give me reply           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449251/google-maps-traffic-api-not-stopping-the-servcie

Comment: @venkat I didn't added the Traffic flow into my app so I have idea about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can GMSMapView Class have a property named trafficEnabled, This property Controls whether the map is drawing traffic data, if available. Defaults to NO.

More - [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#aba119ffe9f9b0c892027656767e59732)

Yes it is live one, with a latency.

No Google doesn't expose historical data.