# Google Maps Traffic api not stopping the servcie

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, traffic

i am doing one application.In that i am using google maps api to show the traffic.Once i open the map to show the traffic,continuously loading,not stoping.So if i go to any other page with service then app is going to crash.So how to stop the traffic service before going to another page.

Comment: stop rendering is deprecated.

Comment: can you show how you integrated the traffic layer in the app?